# posbox Can't start odoo.py

Tags: odoo

I've downloaded  [the latest image (v15)](https://nightly.odoo.com/trunk/posbox/) and installed it  on the raspberry pi 3.

It boots properly, but when I try to start odoo.py I get the error that /home/pi/.local is a read-only file system.

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to start the Odoo manually? Isn't that the Odoo will be automatically started.

Comment: give a look to the image I just added ... is it supposed to display such screen?